# What is meant by "find server's default route"?

Tags: unix, networking

I have an assignment and the teacher is asking us to use unix to find the server's default route, I'm not quite sure what is meant by this. 
He also asks "What is the unix one line command that you use to output only the hostname(or IP) of the default route? " I know I need to use the route command but after that I'm a little bit lost. Please let me know,

Thanks

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask this question _and_ the answer is probably recoverable with a bit more googling _but_ you should still try it yourself before asking :)

Answer (score 0):

route -n |grep ^0.0.0.0

or

netstat -rn |grep ^0.0.0.0

bsd has a "route print" but I forget the syntax